# Releasing the find and replace pane in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012 the find and replace window has Docking alignment to the top right side, how to release it?

[image]

Comment: @FurkanEkinci, I didn't modify the default settings, it was originally docked.

Comment: Oh, sorry. This find section is annoying me too and I think it is embedded to code window. I use _ctrl+shift+f_ shortcut but it doesn't taste the same.

Answer (score 0):

The "quick find" window isn't docked in the usual sense. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to dismiss it and also make the yellow-orange search result highlighting go away.

Alternatively, click the X in the top right of the mini window.

Answer (score 0):

```
Edit.Find = docked Find window

Edit.Replace = docked Replace window

Edit.FindinFiles = undocked Find window

Edit.ReplaceinFiles = undocked Replace window
```

so for undocked windows you can press Ctrl + Shift + F or Ctrl + Shift + H

or alternatively change shortcuts in Options > Environment > Keyboard to reach desired windows easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unfortunately, which really drives me nuts when trying to find something in a minified file (single line) since the find window commonly blocks the found result.

Last post I could find about it:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/3636907-let-me-undock-the-find-and-replace

The best solution I can find is copy and past file into notepad and find there (for my needs).

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio 2012 all docked windows can be released as follows;

> **Docked Window's Header** right click menu (*or click **Window Position Icon** what located the far right of the header*)> **Float** menu

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the question with a snapshot because the right click is not working in any corner.

Answer (score -1):

If the usual things, as already suggested, won't work, here are two other ideas I have found to work with oddities in Visual Studio.

1. Disable all plugins and try again (had a weird case of VS crashing on Ctrl+S and it was a faulty plugin)
2. Try a repair on the install, could have some faulty files.